# Meteor package unit test with using database

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor

I has got a problem.
I try to create unit test for meteor package with using database.

For this reasons in official guide recommended to use Factory from dburles:factory package.

I add it to my packages dependency

```
Package.onTest((api) => {
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('practicalmeteor:chai');
  api.use('dburles:factory');
```

and import it to my test file

```
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
```

than I try to use it:

```
describe('UserUtils getProfilePicture function test ', () => {
  it('get profile picture from profile.image field', () => {
    let users2 = new Mongo.Collection('users');
    Factory.define('userFactory', users2, { name: 'Test user' });
  });
});
```

but I has got only error message in my test

```
Error: Factory.define is not a function
```

If anybody know, please help me. What i do wrong?

Comment: It looks like the `dburles:factory` package doesn't `export` the `Factory` object, so it should be global. So, you shouldn't need to use the import statement at the top of the test file. There are other examples in the Meteor Testing Guide that use the `meteor/factory` package, which might be what's so confusing.

Comment: Here
https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#generating-test-data
Is recomended to use dburles:factory package.
I already tryed to use meteor/factory, but a has got an error - package does not exisits.
I gess that dburles:factory in the atmosphere and meteor/factory is the same packages.